# Unblock (jQuery BlockUI) after file sent to browser through response stream

Tags: asp.net, jquery, blockui

I have an `<asp:button />` that generates a PDF report. I want to use jQuery BlockUI to display a message that says: Generating Report..

Using: `Response.BinaryWrite` I am then sending the file to the user so it appears as a file download in the browser.

I cannot get `$.unblockUI();` to fire. As soon as the file download begins or has completed or is cancelled I want it to dissappear. Currently it never does.. It's as though the page hasn't been re-loaded, I've hit the server but it comes back with the same page.

Things I have tried:

- Setting a variable in JS to true so on  `document.ready()` it will call a function if set to true. This doesn't work because even though I change the variable in code it doesn't change the HTML that is sent to the client.
- This sort of thing: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() { $.unblockUI; }); //register with Microsoft way
  $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); //double the insurance and register with jquery way` 
  never gets called..

Can this be achieved with an updatepanel?

Any thoughts?

Also in case it helps:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & ShortFilename & """")
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length)
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```

I can see why this doesn't work sort of, the page is not refreshing in anyway there's just a response stream being sent to the browser, but surely there's an event I can latch on to?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: It's effectively impossible to do it the way I originally intended as returning a stream does not re-load the page or allow you to pass any custom logic..

Comment: The solution is to do all of the processing with the loading screen showing, then either return a response that will remove BlockUI and then request the file you want to stream, or redirect them to a page which will re-request the stream.. You need to keep the file on the hard drive temporarily to do this though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first block the UI as normal. Then make an AJAX request to your report generator, when the PDF is generated store it locally for a short time, or have it in a temporary folder that is cleared out when the user logs out or their login times out. Have the report generator return a success message and a URL.

Have the client ajax request handle the success message, remove BlockUI, then call the URL using:

```
window.location="http://yourURL/temp/report.pdf
```

The browser will start to download the file and you are done!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660817/181197

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to create a child window that does the PDF loading and let the parent figure out when the child window has closed or something.

[Is it possible for parent window to notice if child window has been closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709400/is-it-possible-for-parent-window-to-notice-if-child-window-has-been-closed)