# Is it possible for parent window to notice if child window has been closed?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have `parent window (opener)` and `child (popup)`

```
----------                      --------------
|         |                     |            |
| parent  | -----> opens popup  |  child     |
|         |                     |            |
-----------                     --------------
```

Let's say, in parent page, I have js function `hello()`

In order for child to call parent's hello() when the child window is closed and also pass an argument, I can do,

```
window.close();
window.opener.hello(someArgument);
```

This will close the window and also call parent's hello();

**But what if I don't want to have the code window.opener.hello() in child page? I mean I want the code to be in parent page only**

One thing I can think of is:

**Somewhat parent knows when the child is closed (event listenr??? not sure in js)
    But in such case how to receive the argument? (i.e. some data back from the child)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious solution (adding an `onunload` event handler property to the pop-up window object) won't work in IE. However, using `attachEvent` does work in IE, so the following will do the job:

```
var win = window.open("popup.html");

function doStuffOnUnload() {
    alert("Unloaded!");
}

if (typeof win.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    win.attachEvent("onunload", doStuffOnUnload);
} else if (typeof win.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    win.addEventListener("unload", doStuffOnUnload, false);
}
```

If you want the pop-up window to pass information to the main window, I'd suggest placing a property in the pop-up's `window` object (e.g. `window.someValue = 5;`). In `doStuffOnUnload()`, you can then pick up on that property: `alert(win.someValue);`

Comment: Just wondering I think then for Firefox there is no way to engage this problem?

Comment: @masato-san: This works for me in Firefox. Does it not for you?

Comment: Yep it works on Firefox (goes into the else statement), though ultimately my child window needs to pass an argument. Maybe I can try putting inner function inside of addEventListener

Comment: win.addEventListener("unload", function() { doStuffOnUnload(win.isSuccess); }, false); Maybe something like this where "isSuccess" is defined in the child window

Comment: Does this work if the child window (i.e. win) loads a page from a different domain? I haven't managed to get this to work in that scenario and am just wondering if I'm screwing up somewhere else.

Comment: @quekshuy: Pretty sure it won't work: scripts running in documents coming from different domains can't talk to each other.

Answer (score 2):

you could attach an `onunload` event to the child window from the parent